# Assigning dynamic values to Excel INDEX query based on drop down cell content

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm new here - I'll try to be concise (and I think I was reasonably thorough in my search). Working with MS Excel 2016, I have the following array formula:

{=INDEX(ACD[**DrugA**],MATCH(A5&B5,ACD[Cell Line]&ACD[Kinase],0))}

"ACD" is a named table in a separate worksheet in the same workbook, and it contains 50 columns of data spanning about 500 rows each. Each column is a different "Drug".

I have a drop down list that populates cell C1 of the worksheet in which the formula operates (let's call this worksheet "Query Table"). The drop down list has 50+ different "Drug" text entries - in addition to "**DrugA**" - from which to choose (DrugB, DrugC, etc.).

I would like to choose an entry from this drop down list and then have that entry replace "**DrugA**" in the formula, thereby redirecting the formula to a different column of values in my "ACD" table. So I'm thinking there must be a command I can embed within the formula that will instruct it to replace "**DrugA**" with the chosen entry from cell C1.

I have been at this for two days with countless Google searches and no solution as of yet. It seems like it should be very simple, but all the simple things I try return errors...so many returned errors. I have some rudimentary vba skills I can bring to bear, but it seems that it shouldn't be necessary. Of course, simply replacing "**DrugA**" with all permutations of "C1" doesn't work. I've explored many command options such as INDIRECT, REPLACE, SUBSTITUTE, but seems LOSER is where I'm redirected.

Any solution(s) that preserve my sanity will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use OFFSET to determine the column.

Consider this table.

[image]

First, an array-free version of your formula:

```
=INDEX(ACD[ccc],MATCH(A5&B5,INDEX(ACD[Cell Line]&ACD[Kinase],0)),0)
```

See how my first column is the drug `aaa`. In order to find the column in which to perform the index, OFFSET can be used like this:

```
OFFSET(ACD[aaa],0,MATCH(C1,ACD[#Headers],0)-1)
```

In words: Find the number of the column with the name in C1 in the ACD table headers, subtract 1 from that number and move that number of columns to the right of column ACD[aaa].

Integrate into the initial formula:

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(ACD[aaa],0,MATCH(C1,ACD[#Headers],0)-1),MATCH(A5&B5,INDEX(ACD[Cell Line]&ACD[Kinase],0),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you teylyn - such a rapid response was more than I was hoping for (but what follows was too slow for the edit time keeper).

I need to carefully explore your answer to better understand your proposed solution - and it will certainly help expand my meager skills. As it turns out, I somehow stumbled onto the solution - though I'm not sure why it worked.

Here is the revision that now works:

```
{=INDEX(INDIRECT("ACD["&$C$1&"]"),MATCH(A5&B5,ACD[Cell Line]&ACD[Kinase],0))}.
```

Seems syntax is everything and having the `&` is key as well as locking cell C1. This is where I went to figure this one out: http://www.excel-bytes.com/how-to-use-index-and-match-in-a-table-with-indirect-in-excel/